# Is this shorter yaml output safe

Tags: python, yaml

I will frequently be using yaml to serialize single values of different data types. I noticed that PyYAML will often add the string `'\n'` or `'\n...\n'` at the end of it's output. In my limited experimentation it seems safe to remove these trailing characters.

**Default behavior**

```
import yaml, decimal, datetime
items = ['hello', 3, True, decimal.Decimal('3.2'), datetime.date(2013, 5, 25)]
for i in items:
    data = yaml.dump(i)
    print '%r %r %r' % (i == yaml.load(data), i, data)
```

will output:

```
True 'hello' 'hello\n...\n'
True 3 '3\n...\n'
True True 'true\n...\n'
True Decimal('3.2') "!!python/object/apply:decimal.Decimal ['3.2']\n"
True datetime.date(2013, 5, 25) '2013-05-25\n...\n'
```

**Strip special trailing characters**

```
import yaml, decimal, datetime
items = ['hello', 3, True, decimal.Decimal('3.2'), datetime.date(2013, 5, 25)]
for i in items:
    data = yaml.dump(i).replace('\n...\n', '').rstrip('\n')
    print '%r %r %r' % (i == yaml.load(data), i, data)
```

will output:

```
True 'hello' 'hello'
True 3 '3'
True True 'true'
True Decimal('3.2') "!!python/object/apply:decimal.Decimal ['3.2']"
True datetime.date(2013, 5, 25) '2013-05-25'
```

So is the second block of code safe. Will it work on all input data. I'm looking for cases where this will break. I'm interested in any case where this will break, even with complex nested input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [trailing elipsis](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760395) optionally denotes the end of the document, which makes YAML self-delimiting. This is useful when embedding multiple YAML documents in the same stream, but if you don't need it, you can safely remove it.

The trailing newline is also optional, but traditional text-parsing tools will expect that every line is ended with a newline. In other words, traditional Unix text processing doesn't view the newline as a *separator* between lines, but as a *terminator* of the current line. Unterminated final line is an exception handled separately (diff's "No newline at end of file" messages come to mind), and is often a source of bugs. You can remove the final newline, but I would advise against doing so without a good reason.